# NavigationMixin Service component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a service component that contains all different types of navigation methods based on NavigationMixin methods. When tried to use the method in a component, it throws an error that NavigationMixin is undefined `[Cannot read property 'Symbol(GenerateUrl)' of undefined]`. In regular LWC components, this would be if I failed to include the NavigationMixin in the class name declaration like

```js
    export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {}
```

Can I use the NavigationMixin methods in a service component at all? I couldn't find any documentation about the same.

Below is the code of my service component

```js
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

    const openRecordViewPage = ( recordId ) => {
        let recordPageUrl = '';
            this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: recordId,
                    actionName: 'view',
                },
            }).then(url => {
                recordPageUrl = url;
                window.open(recordPageUrl);
            })
            .catch( exception => {
                console.error(`Exception in openRecordViewPage(): ${JSON.stringify(exception)}`);
            });
    }

    export {openRecordViewPage};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a class for this to work:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

const Q296547 = (superclass) => class extends NavigationMixin(superclass) {
    openRecordViewPage(recordId) {
        let recordPageUrl = '';
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: recordId,
                actionName: 'view',
            },
        }).then(url => {
            recordPageUrl = url;
            window.open(recordPageUrl);
        })
        .catch( exception => {
            console.error(`Exception in openRecordViewPage(): ${JSON.stringify(exception)}`);
        });

    }
}

export { Q296547 }
```

And from there, in your main code, use this mixin like any other:

```
import { Q296547 } from 'c/Q296547';

export default class MyOtherComponent extends Q296547(LightningElement) {
    // main code here //
}
```

Comment: When I tried to use this, I get an error "Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined". I might be doing it wring:  ``` lang-js import { Q296547 } from 'c/pageNav';

export default class NavTestComponent extends Q296547(LightningElement) {
    // main code here //
    recordId = 'a1RN0000005gvNPMAY';

    handleButtonClick(){
        // this[Q296547.openRecordViewPage](this.recordId);
        Q296547( this.recordId );
    }
}  ```